# How to dynamically set blob name to store in Blob storage in azure function nodejs?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have a activity function that should store message in Blob storage.I can overwrite a file in blob storage but i need to store data in different name.how to do that? Azure function doesn't support dynamic binding in nodejs.

[image: function.json]

Comment: You want to define your own blob name or a random name like [sys.randGuid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#contextbindingdata-property) is acceptable?

Comment: i have used "path" : "azureblob/{rand-guid}" it gives a unique name. but is there a way to specify the name? @JerryLiu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find one workaround, see whether it's useful.

Along with blob output binding, there's an activity trigger to receive message `msg`, we can put self-defined blob name in `msg` for blob binding path to consume.

In your orchestrator function which calls Activity function

```
yield context.df.callActivity("YourActivity", {'body':'messagecontent','blobName':'myblob'});
```

Then Activity function code should be modified

```
context.bindings.myOutputBlob = context.bindings.msg.body;
```

And its function.json can use blobName as expected

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "activityTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name":"myOutputBlob",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "path": "azureblob/{blobName}"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```